# sort vector for index

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a very simple question, and I think I am simply doing something stupid, but cannot find the bug for hours....

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int uint;

enum {ASCEND, DESCEND};

template<typename T>
bool ascend_sort(pair<uint, T> i, pair<uint, T> j){return j.second>i.second;}

template<typename T>
bool descend_sort(pair<uint, T> i, pair<uint, T> j){return i.second>j.second;}

template<typename T>
void sortIdx(vector<uint>& idx, const vector<T>& src, int dir=ASCEND){
    vector< pair<uint, T>  > tmp (src.size());
    for (uint i=0; i<src.size(); i++){
        tmp.push_back(pair<uint, T>(i, src[i]));
        cout << i << " " << src[i] << " \n";
    }

    if (dir==ASCEND){
        sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), ascend_sort<T>);
    }else{
        sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), descend_sort<T>);
    }

    idx.resize(src.size());

    for (uint i=0; i<src.size(); i++){
        idx[i] = (tmp[i].first);
        cout << tmp[i].first << " \n" ;
    }
}
```

Why does http://ideone.com/HOnvI work and  http://ideone.com/R6H0n not....

the codes only differ in sorting ascendantly and descendantly. I also tested sorting without map (sort the vector directly), and it works fine there.

Comment: Your `tmp` vector is first constructed with a size and then you use `push_back`. This is not what you want. Your comparators are odd and take arguments by value. Taking arguments by non-const reference (like `idx` is an anti-pattern). Kill it with fire.

Comment: yes, push_back was the problem. why are my comparators odd?  how else can I pass the output without copying 'index'?

Comment: The comparators simply should take their arguments by reference to const. Also, don't invert the argument order, invert the comparison used. Makes it a hell lot easier to read. Just return by value.

Comment: well, the pairs are not large, but ref is better than value here. I don't agree with you on the second point though, why should I return by value? that would cause the entire vector to be copied unnecessarily.

Comment: On a modern compiler the vector is simply moved, on every older industrial-grade compiler it is subject to NRVO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
vector< pair<uint, T>  > tmp (src.size());
```

Creates a vector of size `src.size()` filled with default elements (here: pair(0, 0.0));

The `.push_back()` adds additional elements to the end of that array (now the size of (2*`src.size()`)

Then after the sort you print only the first `src.size()` elements, which are all the initial 0,0.0 ones

To fix, just declare the vector empty:

```
vector< pair<uint, T>  > tmp;
```